# AutoMapper и спецификация

Tags: c#, automapper

Использую AutoMapper 12.0.1, LinqSpec 3.2.0

Описал спецификацию для выборки, чтобы можно было переиспользовать и в AutoMapper, но получаю ошибку:

```
Unable to create a map expression from . (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[IdentityServer.Domain.Models.Identity.KvcApplicationRole,System.Boolean]]) to Boolean.CanBeDeleted (System.Boolean)

Mapping types:
KvcApplicationRole -> RoleDto
IdentityServer.Domain.Models.Identity.KvcApplicationRole -> IdentityServer.Core.DTOs.RoleDto

Type Map configuration:
KvcApplicationRole -> RoleDto
IdentityServer.Domain.Models.Identity.KvcApplicationRole -> IdentityServer.Core.DTOs.RoleDto

Destination Member:
CanBeDeleted
```

Сам маппинг описан так:

```
CreateMap<KvcApplicationRole, RoleDto>()
    .ForMember(x => x.RoleId, x => x.MapFrom(m => m.Id))
    .ForMember(x => x.GroupId, x => x.MapFrom(m => m.GroupId ?? 0))
    .ForMember(x => x.GroupName, x => x.MapFrom(m => GetGroupName(m.Group)))
    .ForMember(x => x.CanBeDeleted, x => x.MapFrom(m => RoleSpecs.CanDelete));
```

При этом, если убрать спецификацию и написать тот же код, который в ней руками, то всё работает как должно.

`m => RoleSpecs.CanDelete.ToExpression().Compile().Invoke(m)` тоже не работает

Полный код, который воспроизводит проблему (#r - для RoslynPad):

```
#r "nuget: AutoMapper, 12.0.1"
#r "nuget: LinqSpecs, 3.2.0"

using AutoMapper;
using LinqSpecs;

var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(x => x.AddProfile<MyProfile>()).CreateMapper();

var first = new First
{
    CanDelete = true,
    Childs = new List<FirstChild> { new FirstChild() }
};

var map = mapper.Map<Second>(first);
map.Dump();

class MyProfile : Profile
{
    private readonly Specification<First> spec = new AdHocSpecification<First>(x => !x.Childs.Any() && x.CanDelete);

    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<First, Second>()
            .ForMember(x => x.CanDeleted, x => x.MapFrom(m => spec));
    }
}

class First
{
    public bool CanDelete { get; set; }
    public List<FirstChild> Childs { get; set; }
}

class FirstChild
{

}

class Second
{
    public bool CanDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `.MapFrom(spec.ToExpression())` А вообще, вы себе "облегчениями" портите жизнь, усложняете ее, а также ухудшаете проект. Например Автомаппер, что вам мешает написать свой конвертор и применить его? Допустим сделать метод расширения, и использовать `fitst.ToSecond()`, будет код в разы чище, понятней, и производительней... Задумайтесь над этим, нужно-ли оно вам.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ У AutoMapper не только маппинг использую, а еще проекции, как минимум. `.MapFrom(spec.ToExpression())` сработал, даже не подумал про это, спасибо. Можете как ответ написать - отмечу.

Comment: Проекция - это тот-же маппинг, который можно сделать руками, без потери производительности и лишнего гемора по типу размазанных по всему проекту конфигураторов и другого лишнего кода. Ответ - еслиб хотел, то написал сразу, можете ответить сами, я не против.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну, производительность у нас не играет ключевую роль, проекты на high-load, под локальном использование в локальной сети, поэтому лишних 5нс на маппинг не жалко потратить)

Answer (score 0):

С разрешения [@EvgeniyZ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220553/evgeniyz) ответ:

В примере с кодом достаточно поменять лямбду с

```cs
.ForMember(x => x.CanDeleted, x => x.MapFrom(m => spec))
```

на

```cs
.ForMember(x => x.CanDeleted, x => x.MapFrom(spec.ToExpression()))
```